# i5-4690 w/ R9 380 and 4x4GB DDR3 - search gatherer (?) keeps crashing the system

Tags: windows-7, crash, search

I've had this for the past week or so, where I boot the pc, log in and everything starts. Then somewhere between 5 minutes and 5 hours (yes, literally), the video display stops and the audio (if applicable) keeps on going for another 5 seconds after which it stutters until I hit the reset button.

Save for two occasions out of 20 and counting, I've not seen a bluescreen.

in event logs, I keep seeing an error followed by two warnings.
Most of the time, the error is about a search gatherer :

```
Windows Search Service failed to process the list of included and excluded locations with the error <30, 0x80040d07, "iehistory://{S-1-5-21-271688168-3521965791-4145341671-1000}/">.
```

A few questions:

- what does it mean?
- what does it (try to) do?
- why does it crash?
- and most importantly: HOW DO I FIX THIS?

I already tested both my boot-drive (SSD) and storage drive (HDD) using HD Tune, not a single problem.
It's not stress-related either as the only thing I'm generally doing is browsing the internet and watching some youtube after a day at the office.

If I need to try/test anything, feel free to tell me. Thanks

Comment: The error in the log is probably unrelated from the crashes you experience, afaik they're harmless. The hangs are definitely hardware issues, sounds like the graphics card or RAM. You could try memtest to try if it's the latter. Good news is this is likely not security related, so you're good on that part.

Comment: I just ran seven memtests with 2 gigabytes each for an hour, and no errors whatsoever. Also followed @zach's advice. I guess now we wait.

Comment: Right. Just booted my pc, started my FTB client and logged in to my server. Within 3 seconds the pc froze, crashed, bluescreened and rebooted. Obviously the RAM is not the problem, but @Zach 's answer didn't fix it either. What do I do now?

Comment: Just ran a 3D Mark FireStrike benchmark. First time it crashed at the start of Graphics 2 test. Rebooted and tried again, no problems (see http://www.3dmark.com/3dm/17714252 for results.) Am going to try this again.

Comment: Crashed again twice, once because Windows wanted to do a different aero scheme or something because the pc was slow, second time  was after the FireStrike demo finished and before the Graphics 1 test (bluescreened). It's quite obvious that it's the graphics card, what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit on the topic, maybe try rebuilding the search index?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a424b496-d135-4cbc-aa76-4293f80ce712/gatherer-error-event-id-3036?forum=w7itproperf

Check Novak Wu's reply on Tuesday, June 29, 2010 3:35 AM

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Now you've found the source i'm gonna put my answer to your comment here because there's not enough room up there :) .

I have to correct myself, this could be a driver issue. The bluescreen usually only doesn't show  on very severe motherboard failures, but of course a simple graphics software issue can do that too...

But anyway, 
Try removing and reinstalling the graphics driver. Or roll back to a previous version of the driver.

If that doesn't fix it, it could be defective VRAM and you could need a new video card.
[Boot into basic graphics mode](https://www.winhelp.us/low-resolution-video-vga-mode-in-windows.html) (F8 boot menu next to safe mode), or remove the video card and run the tests to see if it crashes on the onboard chip. If it is, look for motherboard specific drivers you might've missed or buy a new MB

Comment: Just uninstalled and reinstalled the video drivers. Not even three seconds after having logged in, I get bluescreened.

How would I go about getting into Basic Graphics mode? I have an F8 option in my BIOS, but it says Q-Flash...

Comment: Tried holding F8 wile it was booting and even faster than before it crashes again. I'm now going to take out the GPU and connect the display directly to the CPU and run FireStrike again.

Comment: Ran FireStrike twice, no problems (except for like 12 times worse framerates but hey, thats what we supposedly have the GPU for...) @J.A.K. What do I do now, as I don't entirely understand your last sentence?